# Change the date format that is being generated from AuthCookie

Tags: c#, sitefinity

In my User control, this code gets a date from my AuthCookie and displays it as a string of text:

```
var renewDate = context.Request.Cookies["AuthCookie"]["RenewalDate"];
```

It outputs:

```
<span class="renew-date">12/31/2019</span>
```

I would like to change this date format to **Dec 31, 2019**. Is there a way to convert this string to date and then display it in a different format?

Comment: Do you want to change the renewalDate value in the cookie or just the display text? If the latter, then just parse the date and then do a .ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")

Comment: Thank you for the tip, Veselin. Parsing it and then .ToString("MMM dd, yyy") worked for me.

Comment: Glad to hear that - I've added it as a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the date that you get from the cookie using [DateTime.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) method and then do a .ToString("MMM dd, yyyy") to get the format you requre.